# VBA Textbox to UTF-8 Textfile

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I got a VBA Script to save the input from a UserForm Textbox to a Textfile.
The Problem is that it's saving it in ANSI coding and not UTF-8.

Is there a way to change this?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call WriteFile("C:\Zuschauer.txt", TextBox1)
End Sub

Sub WriteFile(ByRef Path As String, ByRef Text As String)
  Dim FileNr As Long
  FileNr = FreeFile
  Open Path For Output As #FileNr
  Print #FileNr, Text;
  Close #FileNr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses `ADODB.Stream` so you'll need to add a reference in your project to `Microsoft Active Data Objects 6.1 Library` (versions other than `6.1` may also work).

```
Sub WriteUnicodeUTF8File(ByVal FileSpec As String, ByVal data As String)
    With New ADODB.Stream
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText data
        .SaveToFile FileSpec, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Depending on your particulars you may need to choose different options such as `adSaveCreateOverWrite`.